# How to modify .htaccess file to rewirite https to specific pages and directories for WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

None of the answers i searched on Google and this site give me the correct answer. It was either because it wasn't for WordPress based platform or it wasn't for pages permalinks.

Anyway, my site using permalinks to get better SEO performance over the regular page ID names. I have one specific page that i want to secure with HTTPS (SSL Socket), a directory under /wp-content/themes/my-theme (/wp-sec), and of course the /wp-admin directory/folder and /login.php page. All the other pages should be HTTP even if i will try to write the link as HTTPS.

The specific page ID is 3519 (/?page_id=3519) and it's permalink is "test".
PLEASE, if you don't know and you are not expert don't answer this question.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into [WordPress HTTPS](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/)? It allows per-page HTTPS without needing to make changes to your `.htaccess` file.  (Not sure if it'll handle the `wp-content/themes/my-theme/wp-sec` folder, though.)

Comment: No plugin can do exactly what i asked, and the plugin you are speaking of long time not supported!

Comment: "...long time not supported" -- according to the link I provided, it was updated in March (**Last Updated:** 2013-3-15).

Comment: Compatible up to: 3.5.2, i tried it about a month ago and it didn't work with 3.6.1 or 3.7.1. Anyway, even if it did i cannot get also directory to work.

Comment: I'm using it with 3.7.1, no problems. For the directory, I think you should be able to use something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7059462/1094518

Comment: How can i use it? My directory is /wp-content/themes/my-theme/wp-sec/ and i want everything in it to be secured... I tired your link today with no success. Thanks for your help.